# how to multiply each row with each row of another matrix elementwise in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have such a matrix

```
m1 = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 1 2 3]
m2 = [ 2 2 2];
```

and I want to multiply each row of m1 with m2 elementwise .

So result is

```
result = [2 4 6; 8 10 12; 2 4 6]
```

How would I do it?

Comment: i always thought m1.*m2 did the trick

Comment: @toxicate20 only in Octave since it already implemented automatic broadcasting

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 bsxfun(@times,m1,m2)


ans =

     2     4     6
     8    10    12
     2     4     6
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
 result = diag(m2)*m1;
```